# Integration of Quickbooks desktop application using PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am new to QuickBooks. I want to use its desktop application(QuickBooks Point Of Sale QBXML v12 SDK ) using PHP. But I am getting any documentation how to integrate the same by PHP.

Can any one tell me is it possible to integrate QuickBooks desktop Application by PHP. If yes, please guide me or provide some good document that I can follow.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to do if you use the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) from GitHub.

You'll want to start by following the [QuickBooks PHP Quick-Start](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start) guide *except* where it says to use:

- docs/example_web_connector.php

Instead use this script from the GitHub repo:

- example_web_connector_point_of_sale.php

Here's a GitHub link for reference while you're reading the rest of this post:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_web_connector_point_of_sale.php

That example will walk you through how to create customers within QuickBooks Point of Sale, from your PHP app. When you decide you want to do other more complicated stuff, you can take that example and build on  it.

You'll want to refer to the [QuickBooks OSR](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) for qbXML reference. Choose the "POS" option on the left-hand menu of the OSR, and then use the "Select Message" drop-down and the "XML Ops" tab to view the XML you can send to QuickBooks. For each different type of action you want to perform within QuickBooks Point of Sale, you'll add a new request and response function as shown in the docs/example_web_connector_point_of_sale.php script I linked to above. e.g. you'll end up writing a bunch of XML-generating functions that look something like this:

```
/**
 * Generate a qbXML request for QuickBooks Point of Sale
 */
function _quickbooks_pos_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
        // We're just testing, so we'll just use a static test request:
        $xml = '
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbposxml version="3.0"?>
                <QBPOSXML>
                        <QBPOSXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                                <CustomerAddRq>
                                        <CustomerAdd>
                                                <CompanyName>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</CompanyName>
                                                 ...
                                        </CustomerAdd>
                                </CustomerAddRq>
                        </QBPOSXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBPOSXML>';

        return $xml;
}
```

You'll likely also want to download [Intuit's SDK](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0260_pos) which has a PDF in it with an absolutely gigantic amount of useful (if a little difficult to navigate/search) information relevant to what you're trying to do.